# Issues with if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am trying to find a keyword in a text file and return the sentence if found. If the keyword is not found I want to call a Writer method. But for some reason the Writer method always runs.

What needs to change to ensure the writer method is only called if the keyword is not found?

Here is my code

```
private static HashMap<String, String[]> populateSynonymMap() {
    responses.put("professor", new String[]{"instructor", "teacher", "mentor"});
    responses.put("book", new String[]{"script", "text", "portfolio"});
    responses.put("office", new String[]{"room", "post", "place"});
    responses.put("day", new String[]{"time",  "date"});
    responses.put("asssignment", new String[]{"homework", "current assignment "});
    responses.put("major", new String[]{"discipline", "focus"," study"});


    return responses;
}
```

Here is my main method and the Writer Method

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    synonymMap= populateSynonymMap(); //populate the map

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;

    System.out.println("Welcome To DataBase ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();           
     String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

    boolean found = false;
    for(String ing : inputs){ //iterate over each word of the sentence.
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String[] value = entry.getValue();
            if (key.equals(ing) || Arrays.asList(value).contains(ing)) {

                    found = true;
                    parseFile(entry.getKey());

                    System.out.println(" Would you like to update this information ? "); 
                String yellow = in.nextLine(); 
                if (yellow.equals("yes")) {
                    removedata(entry.getKey());
                }
                if (yellow.equals("no")) {
                    System.out.println("Have a good day"); 
                    break;
                }


                    break;
                    //System.out.println("Have a good day!");
                   // break;
            }
        }
        if(found){
             Writer();
        }   
    }
}
}


 public static void Writer() {
    boolean endofloop = false;
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File("data.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            file.getAbsoluteFile(), true))) { // Creates a writer object
                                                // called wr
                                                // file.getabsolutefile
                                                // takes the filename and
                                                // keeps on storing the old
        System.out.println("I do not know, Perhaps you wanna help me learn?"); // data
        while ((Keyboard.hasNext())) {

            String lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print(" is this correct ? ");
            String go = input.nextLine();

            if (go.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println("enter what you want to teach me");
                lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.print(" is this correct ? ");
                go = input.nextLine();
            }

            if (go.equals("yes")) {
                wr.write(lines);
                wr.write("\n");

                wr.newLine();

                wr.close();
            }

            System.out.println("Thankk you");
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" cannot write to file " + file.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should reset `found` flag after processing each word.

Comment: You need to fix your formatting so it is consistent and easy to read. You currently mix K&R and Java styles. Your indentation is an inconsistent mix of tabs and spaces. I made it better, but you should consistently make it good. You can use tools like your IDE's internal formatter, or ident, or such.

Comment: woha thats an awful lot of uneeded code. :)

Comment: You shoud also try to avoid using multiple scanners, you should use lower case method names and I am not sure where `responses` is declared. Your current (incomplete) code does. The yes/no code in writer needs cleanup, too but your question was not about that, right?

Comment: @eckes what you suggest for the yes/no in my writer method?

Comment: @Eggz depends on what you want it to use. First of all I would write a method getYesOrNo() which does input reading, parsing, retry if something is wrong. Then your code gets shorter.

Comment: ahaa.. Well that makes sense. But I am a beginner when I make it to your level I will transition into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call writer if not found, then you must use:

```
if (!found) writer();
```

Your break is only terminating the inner loop, you might want to add an

```
if (found) break;
```

to terminate the outer loop as well (you did not say if this is required or not).

Comment: I wanted to search the input till a keyword is found, if no keyword is found then call the writer method

Comment: Yes but the question is what you want to do if more than one is found. If you want to only react on the first you need the second break.